# how to assign an object to smarty templates?

Tags: php, smarty, viewmodel, variable-assignment

i created a model object in PHP

```
class User {
  public $title;

  public function changeTitle($newTitle){
    $this->title = $newTitle; 
  }
}
```

How do i expose the property of a User object in smarty just by assigning the object?

I know i can do this

```
$smarty->assign('title', $user->title);
```

but my object has something like over 20 plus properties.

Please advise.

**EDIT 1**

the following didn't work for me.

```
$smarty->assign('user', $user);
```

OR

```
$smarty->register_object('user', $user);
```

then i try to `{$user->title}`

nothing came out.

**EDIT 2**

I am only currently trying to output the public property of the object in the smarty template. Sorry if i confused any one with the function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me.

```
$smarty->register_object('user', $user);

// Inside the template. note the lack of a $ sign
{user->title}
```

This one doesn't work regardless whether i have the $ sign

```
$smarty->assign('user', $user);
```

I hope someone can tell me why.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to access any public properties of an object from a Smarty template. For instance:

```
$o2= new stdclass;
$o2->myvar= 'abc';
$smarty->assign('o2', $o2);

### later on, in a Smarty template file ###

{$o2->myvar}  ### This will output the string 'abc'
```

You can also use `assign_by_ref` if you plan on updating the object after assigning it to the Smarty template:

```
class User2 {
  public $title;
  public function changeTitle($newTitle){
    $this->title = $newTitle; 
  }
}
$user2= new User2();
$smarty->assign_by_ref('user2', $user2);
$user2->changeTitle('title #2');
```

And in the template file

```
{$user2->title}  ## Outputs the string 'title #2'
```

Comment: sorry it didn't work for me. I am not sure why. Please see my EDIT 1.

Comment: Are you calling `$user->changeTitle()` before or after assigning the object to Smarty?

Comment: my apologies. i am currently trying to output the property of the object. let me put in another EDIT message

Answer (score 2):

```
$smarty->assign('user', $user);
```

in template

```
{$user->title}
```

Comment: sorry it didn't work for me. I am not sure why. Please see my EDIT 1.